# Saving a unfed kitten

Tags: cats, health

A small kitten orphaned since few days is in our neighborhood. Last two days it didn't eat much and it had in last two days is a pinch of fish. The situation worsened today and it was lying down as if waiting to die.. I bought some cow milk and tried to force feed 50ml by feeding bottle and left it after pouring on it some water. To my awful disappointment it become motionless and after a while it peed the milk I fed and vomited some through mouth.. the breathe become very less. I am not sure it will get alive. What I should do?

Comment: First of all never give cow milk to kitten. It is very difficult to digest. Buy kitten formula from pet store, and prepare milk.

Comment: Secondly, immediately visit a vet wasting no time.

Comment: It is extremely bad thing to force feed cow milk to a kitten. The kitten may die because of this.

Comment: Meanwhile, from local medical shop buy human electrolyte solution and a 50 ml syringe. Try feeding the cat electrolyte solution using the syringe. And also once the pack is opened, pour entire powder into water and store remaining water in refrigerator. Never leave some powder unused. It will get contaminated.

Comment: And immediately the cat needs a medicine injection which only the vet can give.

Comment: I have no option whatsoever to take it to a vet the reason that this is a remote village

Comment: Depending on how old the kitten is, she may only be able to be fed from a dropper. You can cause aspiration pneumonia by force feeding with a syringe.  This is sad, it doesn't sound like there is much you can do. Cats are lactose intolerant so cow's milk is not the best. Perhaps water it down.. Just keep the kitten warm and hold her. If you cannot take her to the vet or buy suitable food or medication for her, that's all you can do at this point, she sounds like she is dying.

Answer (score 3):

First of all , take it to the vet. Secondly, kittens sometimes may not eat when they are sick. Same thing happened with my kitten, it became sick,vomited and there was runny stool. Didn't eat any thing whole day, lay down on the floor , whenever tries to get up, shakes and again lay down. Vet injected him and after few hours he was fine. 
So the only hope for him is to take to the vet, save a life , go to heaven.

It must not be an answer but a comment, but I cannot comment due to low rep.

Comment: stop giving the cat milk, it can make diarrhea worse.

Comment: I just checked the cat, it is okay now but still resting